# Dual boot menu missing after upgrading from Bionic Beaver to Focal Fossa

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I can no longer see the dual boot menu to select whether to launch Ubuntu or Windows (8.1) after I have upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04; now, Ubuntu just launches straight up, after displaying my the model of my computer (Lenovo) and then followed by a new screen that displays both model of my computer and Ubuntu.

I have tried running:

```
sudo update-grub
```

but that didn't do anything.

If it matters, here are the contents of my `/etc/default/grub`

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

EDIT:

Results from running `sudo efibootmgr`

```
BootCurrent: 000E
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 000E,000C,0000,0006,000D,0004,0008,0005,0007,0009,000B
Boot0000* fedora
Boot0001  Setup
Boot0002  Boot Menu
Boot0003  Diagnostic Splash
Boot0004* USB FDD:
Boot0005* ATAPI CD:
Boot0006* USB HDD: Generic Flash  Disk
Boot0007* USB CD:
Boot0008* ATA HDD: WDC WD10S21X-24R1BT0-SSHD-8GB           
Boot0009* PCI LAN: EFI Network (IPv4)
Boot000A* Lenovo Recovery System
Boot000B* PCI LAN: EFI Network (IPv6)
Boot000C* Fedora
Boot000D* Windows Boot Manager
Boot000E* ubuntu
Boot0019* Lenovo Recovery System
```

Comment: Have you tried the `Shift` key at boot to reveal grub menu? Also, might want to comment out `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried both of those, but neither work for some reason...

Comment: `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` if this shows uefi `sudo efibootmgr ` please.

Comment: @mikewhatever I've updated my post with the output of that.

Comment: also, I have tried changing the timeout via sudo efibootmgr -t 10 and restarting my computer but that did not do anything either.